# Difference between runtime and compile group

Tags: gradle

In a gradle build script I've the following piece of code:

```
dependencies {
   runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '4.1.1'
}
```

and it works fine, but if I change it to

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '4.1.1'
}
```

an exception will be thrown during `gradle build`

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.1/sprin
g-core-4.1.1.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.1/sprin
g-core-4.1.1.jar
```

I thought the artifact searching for in the same place for both compile and runtime. What are differences between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle resolves `compile` dependencies before it performs compilation, expecting that the source code will reference the artifact directly. However, it does not resolve `runtime` dependencies until later in the build process. (See @Dónal 's answer for usage guidelines in choosing between `compile` and `runtime`)

Thus, it is most likely that the difference between the two cases is that your `build` task required compilation, but not runtime prep. With your original configuration, any task requiring runtime prep would have failed with the same error.

To fix the failure in this *specific* case, I recommend changing your `version` value from `4.1.1` (which is not in the Maven repository you reference) to `4.1.1.RELEASE` (which is).

Comment: Hmmm. Looks like @Dónal took down his answer. IIRC the just of his guideline was... If your code contains an import statement that references a class found in the dependency, then you should use `compile`. Otherwise you should use `runtime`.

Comment: A good example of this would be having a Java library as a compile dependency and its implementation as a runtime dependency.  `compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1'` and `runtime 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.1'` for a REST client as an example.

Comment: If the individual who voted this answer down would be so kind as to explain the problem with it I would greatly appreciate it.